# Transitive binary Relation on sets

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Consider a set ,
A = { 1 , 2 , 3 }

```
  Subset = { (1,3) , (1,2) }
```

is a transitive relation .
But I don't get that how it is transitive relation because there is no ordered pair whose first member is 3 .

Comment: It is vacuously transitive.  There are no relation pairs of the form $(a,b) , (b, c)$ so there are no counterexamples no transitivity.

Comment: Hello lulu , but our teacher and textbook provided a lot of examples in which it says it's transitive where even ( b,c) pair don't exist in subset . And I never heard of vacuously transitive , why it shouldn't be called un-transitive or non-transitive ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transitive means that $xRy\wedge yRz \Rightarrow xRz$.

In your example, the premise $xRy \wedge yRz$ is not fulfilled and so the relation is transitive.

In case of $R=\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$, the relation would not be transitive, since the premise holds, but $(1,3)$ is missing in $R$.

Comment: Thank you but If the premise is not fulfilled then how it can be transitive? It is clearly against the definition of transitive relation which says that if ( a,b ) belongs to R and (b,c) belongs to R , then (a,c) must belong to R . Since , here is no (b,c) pair , hence the relation should be said unquestionably and blindly as non-transitive . Please correct if I am wrong somewhere .

Comment: Does transitive also means( given that a,b and x belongs to the set considered) if (a,b) belongs to R and (a,x) belongs to R then it is transitive given that no element exist whose first member is 'b' ?

Comment: @Get_Maths: Indeed, it's transitive.

Comment: Okay thank you .